# Design of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have question about graphic design of android application. On [this link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-nested-viewpager-fragment-tabs-tutorial/) you can see my ActionBar in my application using SherlockActionBar. But I want something like on [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.restauracie.android.app&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInNrLnJlc3RhdXJhY2llLmFuZHJvaWQuYXBwIl0). Where can I learn how to do something like that or where can I edit my ActionBar.

Comment: i am not sure if thats a native ActionBar.Seems non native to me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using SherlockActionBar for this. I've tried and it just seems so messy and difficult to implement.

In May 2013, Google released a new support library for this kind of [Drawer Layout](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) which uses fragments. It's very easy to implement and there are many examples showing how.

#### Edit:

i see now that on the link you provided, they were using the support library I referred to. However, I do suggest you take a look at the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html), specifivally v7, which will allow you to use the Action Bar in previous version of android, rather than relying on a 3rd-party software package like ABS.